# How can I use multiple variables in one string under for /F

Tags: batch-file

**Short version:** My script lets you input a a couple of things and a **number** and then it looks for that file. Easy. Now I want you to enter a bunch of numbers and the script will look for files including any of those numbers. I understand how to do this with multiple strings, but the script gets messy.

This is what I got when its looking for one file.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set /p "example1"=blabla: "
set /p "example2"=blabla: "
set /p "Number=Number: "
Echo Will search for : %example1%example2%%number%.pdf
for /R "my location" %%a in (%example1%example2%%number%.pdf) do (
blablabla
)
```

This works. Adding multiple %number% will make it look like this the way I now do it...

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set /p "example1"=blabla: "
set /p "example2"=blabla: "
set /p "Number1=Number: "
  IF [%Number1%] EQU [] echo Moving to next step & goto Next_step
set /p "Number2=Number: "
  IF [%Number2%] EQU [] echo Moving to next step & goto Next_step
set /p "Number3=Number: "
  IF [%Number3%] EQU [] echo Moving to next step & goto Next_step

:next step   REM Here comes the messy part

Echo Will search for : %example1%%example2%%number1%.pdf
Echo Will search for : %example1%%example2%%number2%.pdf
Echo Will search for : %example1%%example2%%number3%.pdf
for /R "my location" %%a in (%example1%%example2%%number1%.pdf) do (
blablabla
)
for /R "my location" %%a in (%example1%%example2%%number2%.pdf) do (
blablabla
)
    for /R "my location" %%a in (%example1%%example2%%number3%.pdf) do (
blablabla
)
```

**To the question:** How can I sum up all of the `%number??%`inputs/variables and use a string like this

```
for /R "my location" %%aa in (%example1%%example2%%AllNumbers%.pdf do (
blablabla
)
```

**I've tried** the !%anything%!, but I'm not sure if I can use it like I want. If its even possible This is what I tried (and some variations of that):

```
rem this is right after all the set /p's shown in the example
Set AllNumbers=!%number1%%number2%%number3%!
Echo Will search for : %example1%%example2%%AllNumbers%.pdf
for /R "my location" %%aa in (%example1%%example2%%AllNumbers%.pdf do (
blablabla
)
```

---

---

---

@npocmaka - thanks for your help. Check my edit below. This is my result. I wish it found all the four files i typed in, but it only found the first. 
[image: test_result]

Final edit: Only thing in picture above left if to remove `/L`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `set number` you can list all variables starting with `number`:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set "example1"=example"
set "example2"=example"
set "Number1=1"
set "Number2=2"
set "Number3=3"


for /f %%# "tokens=2 delims==" in ('set number') do (
    for /R "my location" %%a in (*%example1%%example2%%%#.pdf) do (
        blablabla
    )

)
```

or you can use `FOR /L`:

```
for /l %%# in (1 ; 1 ; 3) do (
    for /R "my location" %%a in (*%example1%%example2%%%#.pdf) do (
        blablabla
    )

)
```

You can iterate a set of numbers with **plain FOR**:

```
for %%# in ( 2 4 12 ) do (
        for /R "my location" %%a in (*%example1%%example2%%%#.pdf) do (
            blablabla
        )
)
```

or

```
for %%# in ( %number1% %number2% %number3% ) do (
        for /R "my location" %%a in (*%example1%%example2%%%#.pdf) do (
            blablabla
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Testing now - The numbers can be anything, depending on what I type after the script is running. Lets say they are 12, 13 and 14. Istead of typing `for /l %%# in (12 ; 13 ; 14) do (` , I did `for /l %%# in (%number1% ; %number2% ; %number3%) do (`  When I try this it seems to only go for the first number (12). At my `do blablabla` I did echo `%%#` and echo `%%a` - but the only result is the file with 12 even tho I know there are files with 13 and 14.

Comment: @MadsTheMan - check my update.May be this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure If I'm doing something wrong here, but have a look at my question - I updated it with the result of testing your edit there.

Comment: remove the `/L`. See `for/?` for the reason.

Comment: @MadsTheMan you have one redundant `/L` in the screen shot on the outer loop.Also put ***** before each file name in the inner loops.

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks for pointing that out. I'm grateful. It now works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way:

```
@echo off
set /p "example1=blabla: "
set /p "example2=blabla: "
set /p "Numbers=Enter all numbers separated by space: "
for %%n in (%Numbers%) do (
   Echo Will search for : %example1%%example2%%%n.pdf
   for /R "my location" %%a in (%example1%%example2%%%n.pdf) do (
      blablabla
   )
)
```

Comment: though a wildcard is still needed in the inner loop because of the `FOR /R`

Comment: @npocmaka: Excuse me? I copy-pasted the original OP's code, and there is _not_ any wild-card there! Why did you inserted a wild-card in your answer?

Comment: I was not aware that you could separate by space in set /p and build it up like that. Thanks for pointing that out. Tried it and it worked. :)

Comment: @MadsTheMan: Thanks! This method is simpler because you may insert a _variable number_ of numbers with no additional code...